# How/where should I put a water dispenser on this counter?

Tags: plumbing, water

My friend's coffee shop has a hot water dispenser they use for drip coffee and tea. It's already filtered, and accessible to customers.

It would be terribly convenient if we customers could get cold drinking water from the same water line. But I don't know where to put a water dispenser faucet, or how to put it there. Perhaps it should mount to the short wood wall in the picture below.

Any suggestions?

[image]